# How to load balance websocket in wso2 API manager gateway?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

For API creation I am able to load balance our services by adding N number of API service urls. 
But how to do the same for load balancing websocket in wso?
As per documentation i didn't see any steps or notes to add another or N number of urls for wso2 websocket API.

Please let me know if I can try out anything to figure out how to handle this issue.

Comment: Are refering to loadbalancing backend endpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're talking about backend endpoints. In that case, you need to have a loadbalancer between the API gateway and your backend servers.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It is about backend endpoints. 

My scenario is that i have two WebSocket services. I want the users/clients to access only one endpoint url. So, I want to define both the services in one wso2 api gateway. If any one of the services are down then the other service can handle it. How can I achieve load balancing.

Comment: Like I mentioned above, you need a loadbalancer between APIM and the backend.